# Accessing the Object in the UpdateView to pass pk for success_url

Tags: django

I want to the user to an view which takes an `pk` as argument.

I want to use the `self.object` in the `UpdateView` to look up the `pk` and pass ist as `args` to the `lazy_reverse` at the  `success_url`.

First of all, is there a better way to do it, and second, how do I access the Object?

Comment: Do you just want to pass the `pk`? You can get the `pk` from `self.kwargs` and then pass it to `reverse_lazy`.

Comment: This might come in handy, but this time I need to make a lookup via the object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest option is to add a [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url) method to your model. Then the `UpdateView` will redirect to this, and you don't need to set `success_url` at all.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_mymodel', args=(self.pk,))
```

If you don't want to do this, then you can't use `success_url` and `reverse_lazy` here, because the url changes for each view depending on the primary key.

Instead, you can use [`get_success_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_success_url). You can access the object with `self.object`.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('view_mymodel', args=(self.object.pk,))
```

Comment: What is the diffrence between the two methods? When should I choose wich?

Comment: Sometimes you might want to use a different URL from `get_absolute_url`, so you need to use `get_success_url`. The rest of the time, using `get_absolute_url` might be a little less repetitive, but it doesn't really matter which you choose.